# how to know the number of words written in a google drive file in a particular day?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm planning to write a CLI program that can count the number of words written in a particular day for a particular file in Google Drive. I wonder **how should look the algorithm able to do that?**

Since Google Drive uses revisions, I don't know how to re-build a file from a range of revisions occurred in a particular day. Assume this scenario

```
file1 is written -> day 0
modifications are made (mam for short) -> rev1, day1'
mam -> rev2, day2'
mam -> rev3, day2''
mam -> rev4, day3'
mam -> rev5, day3''
mam -> rev6, day3'''
```

I dream with a CLI utility that I could say it, *google-drive-wc file1 day2* and it returns the number of words [by default] written in *day2*, where *day2* has a particular format e.g. mm-dd-yy.

Thanks so much for your advice,

Comment: What have you tried? We're much better at answering more specific questions, like "how do I count the number of words in a file" or "How do I access Google Drive's revisions" than more general scenarios.